# Handling POST request Flask

Tags: python, post, web, flask

I am trying to pass data from my website's login page as a POST request to Flask. However, Flask fails to obtain any data. Here's a code snippet of my test.py file that runs the Flask app. I realised that the code isn't entering the method itself.Can anyone help me understand where am I going wrong?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    processed_text = text.upper()
    print "Processed text is..."
    print processed_text
    return processed_text
```

Here's the snippet of my login form:

```
div class="modal fade" id="direct-login-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="direct-login-form-label" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
          <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                      </button>
                       <h4 class="modal-title" id="direct-login-form-label">Login</h4>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="wrap-login-form wrap-reviews">
                      <form id="direct-login" form action="." method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-3" for="direct_username">Username</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" id="direct_username" placeholder="Username">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-3" for="direct_password">Password</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="direct_password" placeholder="Password">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-slidecheck clearfix">
                          <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="slidecheck">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="direct_remember_me" name="check" />
                              <label for="direct_remember_me"></label>
                            </div>
                            <span>Remember me</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-3"></label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <button type="submit" name="my-form" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">Submit</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-3"></label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <p class="help-block"><a href="../../vxeg/indexc2b6.html?action=lostpassword">Lost your password?</a><span> or </span><a href="../../membership-account/index.html">Register an Account</a></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="direct_security" name="direct_security" value="f0abedaf74" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/directory-category/coffee-lounge/" />                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I simulated your problem on my machine it worked !
I made the following changes.

for view

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('register.html')


@app.route("/register", methods=['POST'])
def register():
    text = request.form['text']
    passwd = request.form['passwd']
    processed_text = text.upper()
    print "Processed text is...", processed_text, passwd
    #do your further processing like saving to Database...
    return render_template('register.html') #send to the profile/dashboard page
```

for html file

```
<form id="direct-login" form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

```
 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="direct_password" name='passwd' placeholder="Password">
```

However you should use [WTF forms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you will have a clean and reusable  code with that.

an example forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[Required(), Email(), Length(1, 64)])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 64), Regexp('^[A-Za-z][A-za-z0-9._]*$', 0,'Username must have only letters, dots, digitsm or underscores')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required(), EqualTo('password2', message='Password must match.')])
    password2 = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')


    '''
    Custome validator for email validate_*
    '''
    def validate_email(self, field):
    if(User.query.filter_by(email= field.data)).first():
        raise ValidationError('Email already registered.')

    '''
    Custome validator for email validate_*
    '''
    def validate_username(self, field):
    if(User.query.filter_by(username = field.data)).first():
        raise ValidationError('Username already registered.')
```

then your html becomes

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %} - Register{% endblock %}
{% block page_content %}
    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: hello @Abhijay if the answer helped you please feel free to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The line containing the opening tag for your form seems like the suspect here:

```
<form id="direct-login" form action="." method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

While I'm not sure if the floating `form` attribute is causing any issues, I'm certain that it isn't doing anything useful so you should get rid of that.

Also, by specifying `action="."`, you are saying that the submission of the form should be directed to the same route that you got the form from. In your Flask code, you wrote

```
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
```

so in your `form` tag, you should specify `action="/"` for the submission to go to the `my_form_post` method in Flask.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the action. It should be `{{ url_for('my_form_post') }}`.

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't seem to solve the issue